# Excel loop that loops through a fixed number of times

Tags: vba, excel

I am working on some formulas in excel VBA and I am trying to make it loop through a certain number of times. Is it possible to do so in VBA and if so how do I do it?

My code is as follows:

```
Sub move()
    If ActiveCell.Offset(0, -1) = ActiveCell.Offset(1, -1) Then
        ActiveCell.Formula = "1"
        ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
    Else
        ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Have a look at `For`, `Do`, `While` for VBA on Google.

Comment: take a look at [Excel reference: Looping - Do Loop](http://www.excel-spreadsheet.com/vba/looping_doloop.htm) and [Excel reference: Looping - For...Loop](http://www.excel-spreadsheet.com/vba/looping_forloop.htm)

Answer (score 9):

To loop through a fixed number of times use a `For...Next` loop.

In your case it would be as follows (I have done it for 10 loops but you can change the number as you wish)

```
Sub move()

Dim i

For i = 1 To 10
    If ActiveCell.Offset(0, -1) = ActiveCell.Offset(1, -1) Then
        ActiveCell.Formula = "1"
    End If
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: +1, but a good idea to drop the `i` from `Next i`. It's not required in VBA and syntatically invalid in VB.NET.

Comment: +1 also. @Bathsheba I never came across that before, thanks for that addition. Only started into VBA in a new job, so advice like this is a little gem in addition to the actual answer, thanks.